# Typescript map a list to function arguments

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a list of arguments looking a little something like this:

```
const args: FeatureEventArg[] = [
  {
    name: 'username',
    type: 'string',
  },
  {
    name: 'message',
    type: 'string',
  },
  {
    name: 'totalMessagesSent',
    type: 'number',
  },
];
```

And my goal is to take that list and with some type, like `FeatreEventArgs<typeof args>` or something, to get arguments for a callback function that would end up looking something like this:

```
function callback(username: string, message: string, totalMessagesSent: number) {
  // Other stuff
}
```

I've managed to get the types part with a lot of fidelling and a lot of `extends "string" ? string` kinda thing. But the names are just `arg_0` instead of the name in the object above.

Anyways, if you have any tips or ideas of how I can achieve this or any other solutions to the problem please let me know.

Comment: I do not understand, do you need to create a type from the type of the list?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible; I have an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44939) about this still open

Comment: Tuple labels and function parameter names are essentially unobservable from the type system; they are only for documentation. The types `(username: string, message: string, totalMessagesSent: number)=>void` and `(x: string, y: string, z: number)=>void` are identical. Also, what exactly do you mean by "get arguments for a callback function"? Is this in a type? Or an actual function implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to drop the `: FeatureEventArg[]` and instead interpret the array of objects `as const` so that the exact string types get preserved. Then you can map over the `[number]` values of the array, extracting the name as the key and the type as the value (through a helper type that transforms the string into the corresponding type).

```
const args = [
  {
    name: 'username',
    type: 'string',
  },
  {
    name: 'message',
    type: 'string',
  },
  {
    name: 'totalMessagesSent',
    type: 'number',
  },
] as const;
type Args = typeof args;
type ToPrimitive<T> =
    T extends 'string' ? string
  : T extends 'number' ? number
  : never;

type ArgsObj = {
  [T in Args[number] as T["name"]]: ToPrimitive<T["type"]>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly, but I have come to the conclusion that my wording in the question was incorrect. I am trying to use it as arguments in a callback function, and I am afraid that that might require a different solution. I updated the question with a more accurate description of my goal if you want to see it